# Centering 4 Images Horizontally and stacking them vertically if the width of the page shrinks?

Tags: html, css, centering

I currently have 4 images on a page. I'd love to center them horizontally, so that when the page shrinks they continue to stay centered. I want to stack them vertically if the page shrinks too much.

Here's a site that does what I'd love to do: http://www.wpexplorer.me/premium/photojax/

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NYcdS/

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png">
<img class ="music" src="http://s18.postimg.org/4st2fxgqh/image.png">
<img class ="projects" src="http://s18.postimg.org/sxtrxn115/image.png">
<img class ="bio" src="http://s18.postimg.org/5xn4lb37d/image.png">
```

### CSS

```
#menu {
    height: 300px;
    width: 1070px;
    background: #222;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.blog {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}

.music {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}

.projects {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}

.bio {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want something as simple as this:

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5W2C2/3/

(Made the images a bit smaller to more easily see what's going on in the jsfiddle)

Is that it?